# The type must implements the inheredit abstract method Iterable<deuda>.iterator()

Tags: java

alguien podría ayudarme con este error? Me dice que implemente iterator() pero eso ya lo tengo implementado. Me salta el error The type monedero must implements the inheredit abstract method Iterable.iterator()

```
public class  monedero implements Iterable<deuda>{
private final Collection<String> propietarios = new HashSet<String>();
private final Collection<actividad> actividades = new LinkedList<actividad>();
private final Collection<deuda> deudas= new HashSet<deuda>();
public monedero(String...prop) {
    for(String elemento: prop) {
        propietarios.add(elemento);

    }
}
public void liquidar(String usu1, String usu2) {
    Iterator<deuda> iterador = this.deudas.iterator();
     while (iterador.hasNext()){
         deuda deud= iterador.next();
        if((usu1.equals(deud.getDeudor()) && usu2.equals(deud.getAcreedor())) || ((usu2.equals(deud.getDeudor()) && usu1.equals(deud.getAcreedor())))){
            iterador.remove();

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Dónde dices que lo tienes implementado? En el código que compartes no está.

Comment: En mis apuntes pone que implementa la interfaz y más abajo pone Iterator<deuda> iterador = this.deudas.iterator() . No pone nada más, que deberia hacer para que no salga ese error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La mera definición de `implements Iterable<deuda>` no hace que la clase implemente la interfaz. Para implementar una interfaz una clase debe proporcionar una implementación de todos sus métodos abtractos.

En tu caso debes proporcionar una implementación para el método `iterator()` (como bien indica el mensaje del error de compilación). Algo como esto (de acuerdo con esta definición `implements Iterable<deuda>`)

```
@Override
public Iterator<deuda> iterator() {
    return deudas.iterator();
}
```

Comment: Vale, funciona. Muchas gracias y perdón por las molestias.

Comment: @Alec si es que esta respuesta a resuelto tu duda, por favor márcala como aceptada, al lado izquierdo hay un signo check ( ✓), el cuál acepta la pregunta y de paso ganas 2 puntos :)